# Terraform fires Cycle error when applying

Tags: terraform, infrastructure

I am trying to build a galera cluster using terraform. To do that I need to render the galera config with the nodes ip, so I use a file template.

When applying, terraform fires an error

```
Error: Cycle: data.template_file.galera_node_config, hcloud_server.galera_node
```

It seems there is a circular reference when applying because the servers are not being created before the data template is used.

How may I circumvent this ?

Thanks

galera_node.tf

```
data "template_file" "galera_node_config" {
  template = file("sys/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf/galera.cnf")

  vars = {
    galera_node0 = hcloud_server.galera_node[0].ipv4_address
    galera_node1 = hcloud_server.galera_node[1].ipv4_address
    galera_node2 = hcloud_server.galera_node[2].ipv4_address
    curnode_ip = hcloud_server.galera_node[count.index].ipv4_address
    curnode = hcloud_server.galera_node[count.index].id
    }
}


resource "hcloud_server" "galera_node" {
  count       = var.galera_nodes
  name        = "galera-${count.index}"
  image       = var.os_type
  server_type = var.server_type
  location    = var.location
  ssh_keys    = [hcloud_ssh_key.default.id]

  labels = {
    type = "cluster"
  }

  user_data = file("galera_cluster.sh")

  provisioner "file" {
    content     = data.template_file.galera_node_config.rendered
    destination = "/tmp/galera_cnf"
    connection {
      type        = "ssh"
      user        = "root"
      host = self.ipv4_address
      private_key = file("~/.ssh/id_rsa")
    }

  }



}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that you have multiple nodes that all depend on each other, and so there is no valid order for Terraform to create them: they must all be created before any other one can be created.

To address this will require a different approach. There are a few different options for this, but the one that seems closest to what you were already trying is to use the special resource type `null_resource` to factor out the provisioning into a separate resource that Terraform can work on only after all of the `hcloud_server` instances are ready.

Note also that the `template_file` data source is deprecated in favor of [the `templatefile` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/templatefile.html), so this is a good opportunity to simplify the configuration by using the function instead.

Both of those changes together lead to this:

```
resource "hcloud_server" "galera_node" {
  count       = var.galera_nodes
  name        = "galera-${count.index}"
  image       = var.os_type
  server_type = var.server_type
  location    = var.location
  ssh_keys    = [hcloud_ssh_key.default.id]

  labels = {
    type = "cluster"
  }

  user_data = file("galera_cluster.sh")
}

resource "null_resource" "galera_config" {
  count = length(hcloud_server.galera_node)

  triggers = {
    config_file = templatefile("${path.module}/sys/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf/galera.cnf", {
      all_addresses = hcloud_server.galera_node[*].ipv4_address
      this_address  = hcloud_server.galera_node[count.index].ipv4_address
      this_id       = hcloud_server.galera_node[count.index].id
    })
  }

  provisioner "file" {
    content     = self.triggers.config_file
    destination = "/tmp/galera_cnf"
    connection {
      type        = "ssh"
      user        = "root"
      host        = hcloud_server.galera_node[count.index].ipv4_address
      private_key = file("~/.ssh/id_rsa")
    }
  }
}
```

The `triggers` argument above serves to tell Terraform that it must re-run the provisioner each time the configuration file changes in any way, which could for example be because you've added a new node: all of the existing nodes would then be reprovisioned to include that additional node in their configurations.

[Provisioners are considered a last resort](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/index.html#provisioners-are-a-last-resort) in the Terraform documentation, but in this particular case the alternatives would likely be considerably more complicated. A typical non-provisioner answer to this would be to use a service discovery system where each node can register itself on startup and then discover the other nodes, for example with [HashiCorp Consul](https://www.consul.io/)'s service catalog. But unless you have lots of similar use-cases in your infrastructure which could all share the Consul cluster, having to run another service is likely an unreasonable cost in comparison to just using a provisioner.

Comment: Unfortunately have to use a deprecated version :(

Answer (score 1):

You really try to use `data.template_file.galera_node_config` inside of your `resource "hcloud_server" "galera_node"` and use `hcloud_server.galera_node` in your `data.template_file`.

To avoid this problem:

1. Remove provisioner "file" from your hcloud_server.galera_node
2. Move this provisioner "file" to a new null_resource e.g. like that:

```
resource "null_resource" template_upload {
  count = var.galera_nodes
  provisioner "file" {
    content     = data.template_file.galera_node_config.rendered
    destination = "/tmp/galera_cnf"
    connection {
      type        = "ssh"
      user        = "root"
      host = hcloud_server.galera_nodes[count.index].ipv4_address
      private_key = file("~/.ssh/id_rsa")
    }
depends_on = [hcloud_server.galera_node]
}
```

Comment: I need to edit this of course. We need to add count to this new resource as well.

Comment: Thanks, both approaches helped me.